# Sum of discrete random variables in Scipy?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

Specifically, I want to make a random variable representing 3d25 by summing 3 uniform discrete distributions from 1 to 25 (scipy.stats.randint(1, 25)). When I try to do this the intuitive way, by just doing

```
d25 = scipy.stats.randint(1, 25)
rv = d25 + d25 + d25
```

I get an error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'rv_frozen' and 'rv_frozen'
```

What is the correct way to do something like this?

Comment: Your question as stated is a little ambiguous. If you want the pmf of the sum of variables, it is the convolution of the pmf of each one. From that you'll get another pmf which can used for other operations (e.g. mean / variance / random sampling etc).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use one of the methods.For example, to select a random variate, use rvs() method.

```
rv = d25.rvs() + d25.rvs() + d25.rvs()
```

Comment: `d25.rvs(size=3)`

Comment: @ev-br. yes, that would make it elegant. sum(d25.rvs(size=3))